# Clicking on folder in iTerm2 opens in web browser instead of Finder

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I have iTerm2 v1.0.0.2 and I am correctly able to open folders in my home directory if command-click on them.  However I am not able to open folders on my Desktop or Documents if I command-click them, instead it opens the folder name in my default web browser. How can I change this so it opens a Finder window as well?

Answer (score 1):

That feature is based on the current directory. For example command-clicking `untitled\ folder` works here:

```
$ cd Desktop; ls
untitled\ folder
```

But not here:

```
$ cd; ls Desktop
untitled\ folder
```